# Filevault for all volumes

Tags: disk-utility, high-sierra, encryption, filevault

I'm using High Sierra, I have my main Macintosh HD encrypted using Filevault. However in Disk Utility there is an option to create new volumes that share space with container. So finally I have volumes Macintosh HD but also Documents, Music and so on. In Disk Utility I can see now:

- Macintosh HD - APFS (encrypted)
- Documents - APFS
- Music - APFS

As you see there is no information for additional volumes that there are also encrypted.

So the question is - are those volumes encrypted or not (and how can I verify that) and if they are not encrypted how can I encrypt them too using FileVault?

This is screen how it looks like in Disk Utility. As you see this Dokumenty partition is not showed as encrypted but when I choose Macintosh HD there is APFS (encrypted)

[image: Disk Utility screen]

This is result of diskutil list:

```
(internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         250.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            93.6 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 22.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                509.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume Dokumenty               12.2 GB    disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume Oprogramowanie          1.9 GB     disk1s6
   7:                APFS Volume D                       18.2 GB    disk1s7
   8:                APFS Volume Muzyka                  35.3 GB    disk1s8
   9:                APFS Volume Inne                    2.9 MB     disk1s9
  10:                APFS Volume S                       2.0 GB     disk1s10
  11:                APFS Volume L                       7.1 MB     disk1s11
```

Comment: This sounds rather strange. I've never seen this. Can you provide a screenshot or if rep is too low run a `diskutil list` in the terminal and copy the output and update your question. The only way this could be true is if you have external Volumes either Partitions or USB,network drives, etc.

Comment: @Jahhein Thanks for interest, I've added screen and command output into question

Comment: That is very strange. The screenshot of the answer below is how a single partition APSF disk should be. If you do a 'diskutil coreStorage list' it will show all encrypted volumes that are connected and they are unlocked or not. However in the end, I think you have another issue with this other than encrypted or not.

Answer (score 1):

When you adding APFS container, you should be able to use APFS (Encrypted)

[image: Add APFS volume]

I found that after added, it will be shown as 'APFS (Encrypted)' in Disk Utility.app. In `diskutil list`, no encryption status is metioned.

I didn't find out how to encrypt / unencrypt an existing APFS volume in Disk Utility.app. Maybe some diskutil command will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Documents and Music a separate partition or the same with the System? Can you post a picture of the disk utility? As I checked mine, all files are encrypted in one drive. You may need to encrypt the separate partition if you opt not to encrypt them before. But if you turn on the Firevault in the beginning then all files should have already been encrypted.

[image]

Comment: I've added screen into question how it looks like on my Mac

Comment: It seems that you have different volumes each mounted at different location. I think only the volume "Macintosh HD" is encrypted and everything else is not. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837  Upon checking information online, Firevault only encrypts startup disk (in your case, "Macintosh HD.") Should you want to encrypt other disks, merge them into one disk or encrypt them separately using password.

Answer (score 0):

Check the article I found on the Apple discussions website regarding FV and APFS. I think it will clarify one or two things. 
The last post by 'etresoft' on the second page is the most interesting one. 
[APFS vs. FileVault](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8087337?answerId=32344897022#32344897022)